# Tackling questions on travel history for visa applications

Tags: visas, uk, history

I am due applying for a UK visa and I have learnt one of the questions is travel history. I have two questions.

1) How does one report the following travel history, for example?

Went to Croatia between 9.4 and 13.4, and on 11.4 one makes a day trip to Bosnia. So, should the travel history look like:

```
Croatia 9.4 - 11.4,
Bosnia 11.4 - 11.4,
Croatia 11.4 - 13.4
```

OR

```
Croatia 9.4 and 13.4
Bosnia 11.4 - 11.4
```

2) I made a trip to Bulgaria. Entering from the Romanian border and exiting from Sofia a few days later. I have the exit stamp from Romanian border which is totally visible.

However, the stamps of entry from the Bulgarian rail-side and the exit by air are not at all visible. In short, it is almost impossible to read the stamps from Bulgaria. I did inform both officers that it is barely visible but they didnt speak proper English and didnt do anything about it.

How will the officer evaluating the travel history see this?